# Logging for C# Webservices

Tags: c#, logging, asmx

We are consuming web services. We use wsdl.exe to generate the client proxy.

How do we keep all the underlying XML files the proxy sends to and receives from the web services provider?

The purpose is to protect ourselves by showing we did have send all the parameters in good format when system malfunctions and disputes arise.

Comment: Why are you using WSDL.EXE? Are you stuck using .NET 2.0? If not, then you should use svcutil.exe instead of the old ASMX technology. Among other benefits, this gives you very easy logging.

Comment: @Kragen: It sounds like you're accusing me of dishonesty. If that's true, then please elaborate. If it's not true, then please clarify your statement.

Comment: @John Sorry - that was @m12345y.

Comment: @all and @Kragen: translation for those as slow as I am: Kragen was addressing m12345y when he spoke of replacing the last sentence. He was not addressing me.

Comment: @John Just an aside note: I understood @Kragen's comment the way he explained it now, and in fact upvoted it. But had a hard time trying to understand why you was so upset. In fact I was tempted to flag your comment for starting  a flame war, which finally decided not to do. So, as you said "for those as slow as I am ...". Have a nice day! :D

Comment: @belisarius: I was admitting that I was being slow.

Comment: @John So was I !! Just saying ... communication is a rather difficult matter. What was obvious for one, sometimes is not even suspected by the other party. It happened to you AND me on this one. :)

Comment: @John: I was only aware of wsdl.exe, thank you for your pointer, i'll get into svcutil later

Comment: @m12345y: I would recommend that you not delay. Using svcutil or "Add Service Reference" would have solved your problem in about five minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did just that using a [SoapExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.aspx) in the application making the web service requests.

The entire system consisted of two classes, a `CopyStream` class that provided the ability to duplicate the contents of a stream to a second stream as it is read / written to, and a `SoapLogger` class that intercepts all SOAP requests and responses in the application and logs them to a file.

You just need to register it in your app.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <soapExtensionTypes>
        <add type="MyNamespace.SoapLogger, MyAssembly" priority="3" group="High" />
      </soapExtensionTypes>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Apologies for the big blob of code, but here it is:

```
/// <summary>
/// Extension to allow logging of SOAP request and response xml.
/// </summary>
public class SoapLogger : SoapExtension
{
    private MemoryStream copyStream;

    public override Stream ChainStream(Stream stream)
    {
        this.copyStream = new MemoryStream();
        return new CopyStream(stream, copyStream);
    }

    public override object GetInitializer(Type serviceType)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override object GetInitializer(LogicalMethodInfo methodInfo, SoapExtensionAttribute attribute)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override void Initialize(object initializer)
    {

    }

    public override void ProcessMessage(SoapMessage message)
    {
        switch (message.Stage)
        {
            case SoapMessageStage.AfterSerialize:
            case SoapMessageStage.AfterDeserialize:
                Log(message);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void Log(SoapMessage message)
    {
        string messageType;
        if (message.Stage == SoapMessageStage.AfterDeserialize)
        {
            messageType = message is SoapServerMessage ? "SoapRequest" : "SoapResponse";
        }
        else
        {
            messageType = message is SoapServerMessage ? "SoapResponse" : "SoapRequest";
        }

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(this.copyStream.ToArray()));
        Logger.Log(string.Format(
            "{0} ({1}):\r\n{2}",
            messageType,
            message.MethodInfo.Name,
            reader.ReadToEnd()
        ));
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Implementation of a stream that wraps an existing stream while copying anything written
/// or read to another stream.
/// </summary>
public class CopyStream : Stream
{
    public Stream BaseStream
    {
        get
        {
            return this.baseStream;
        }
    }
    private Stream baseStream;

    public Stream OtherStream
    {
        get
        {
            return this.otherStream;
        }
    }
    private Stream otherStream;

    public CopyStream(Stream BaseStream, Stream OtherStream)
    {
        if (BaseStream == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("BaseStream");
        }
        if (OtherStream == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("OtherStream");
        }

        this.baseStream = BaseStream;
        this.otherStream = OtherStream;
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get
        {
            return this.BaseStream.CanRead;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get
        {
            return this.BaseStream.CanSeek;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get
        {
            return this.BaseStream.CanWrite;
        }
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        this.BaseStream.Flush();
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get
        {
            return this.BaseStream.Length;
        }
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get
        {
            return this.BaseStream.Position;
        }
        set
        {
            this.BaseStream.Position = value;
        }
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        int returnValue = BaseStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
        this.otherStream.Write(buffer, offset, returnValue);
        return returnValue;
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        try
        {
            this.OtherStream.Seek(offset, origin);
        }
        catch { }
        return BaseStream.Seek(offset, origin);
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        try
        {
            this.OtherStream.SetLength(value);
        }
        catch { }
        this.BaseStream.SetLength(value);
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        try
        {
            this.OtherStream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
        }
        catch { }
        this.BaseStream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    }
}
```

Its not been performance / stress tested, but it seems to be holding up just fine - *hopefully* the way that the stream copying is done should mitigate any performance impact.

Comment: SoapLogger class will be at client end from where web service will be called or does it stay at server end.if possible please clarify

Comment: @Thomas This is in the application making the web service requests (i.e. the client) I've added a note to the question to clarify this.